# Error E175013 by using SVN over XCode 6 (OSX 10.9)

Tags: xcode, macos, svn, osx-mavericks, xcode6

I want to use a repository from a server which is located in the intranet. When i try to checkout over xcode it's "unable to connect" (E175013) and when i try to update/commit from an already checked out project the "Access is forbidden" (also E175013).

XCode SVN works fine over the internet with a svn repo from e.g. code.google. The svn in the intranet works fine over the Terminal.

So what is missing or what i'm doing wrong? Maybe XCode got a problem with a self-signed certificate? How could i solve this?

I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score -1):

Check my answer to your posting on the Apple Developer Forums.  If it helps at all I'll repost it here.